# Sufficient conditions for an indefinite real symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-semidefinite

Given a real symmetric matrix $S$ of order $n$, assuming $\mathbf{x} \equiv \mathbf{e}_i$ with $i \in [1,\,n]$ we have:

$$
\mathbf{x}^t\,S\,\mathbf{x} = s_{i,i}
$$

so if $s_{i,i}=0$ for at least one $i \in [1,\,n]$ it follows that $S$ cannot be definite (positive or negative).

If in addition $\det(S) \ne 0$, then all the eigenvalues of $S$ aren't zero and consequently $S$ is indefinite.

In this way we have proof a first thesis:

$$
\color{blue}{\boxed{\text{If a non-singular real symmetric matrix has a zero on the diagonal it's indefinite.}}}
$$

On the other hand, after some numerical experiments, I noticed that $\det(S)=0$ implies that $S$ is a semi-definite matrix (positive or negative) only when the i-th row considered is all zeros.

This leads me to formulate a second thesis:

$$
\color{green}{\boxed{\text{If a real symmetric matrix has a non-zero row with a zero on the diagonal it's indefinite.}}}
$$

For $n = 1$ or $n = 2$ the thesis is trivially true, while for $n = 3$ I thought I'd consider:

$$
S = 
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & c \\
b & d & e \\
c & e & \color{\red}{0} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

under the condition $c^2+e^2\ne 0$ and we start with the calculation of the determinant:

$$
\det(S) = 2\,b\,c\,e - a\,e^2 - c^2\,d\,.
$$

Having done this, it's evident that if $c=0$ the determinant vanishes only if $a=0$ and in this case:

$$
\text{eig}(S) = \left\{0,\,\frac{d\pm\sqrt{d^2+4\left(b^2+e^2\right)}}{2}\right\}
$$

where the two non-zero eigenvalues are always discordant and therefore $S$ is indefinite.

On the other hand, if $c \ne 0$ the determinant vanishes only if $d = \frac{2\,b\,c\,e-a\,e^2}{c^2}$ and in this other case:

$$
\text{eig}(S) = \left\{0,\,\frac{a\,c^2+\left(2\,b\,c-a\,e\right)e \pm \sqrt{c^2+e^2}\sqrt{a^2\,c^2+\left(2\,b\,c-a\,e\right)^2+4\,c^4}}{2\,c^2}\right\}
$$

where the two non-zero eigenvalues are always discordant and therefore $S$ is indefinite.

> For $n > 3$ the calculations get too complicated, ideas on how to proceed? Thanks!

Comment: your matrix $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & \text{i} \\
1 & \text{i} & \color{\red}{0} \\
\end{bmatrix}$ is not "semi-definite" as asserted since it is complex but non-real and not Hermitian.

Comment: *"On the other hand, after some numerical experiments, I noticed that det()=0 implies that  is a semi-definite matrix (positive or negative) only when the i-th row considered is all zeros."* why don't you prove this statement to yourself.  Hint: suppose matrix is PSD and write $A = B^TB$.  Alternatively: I infer you've already proven the $2\times 2$ case so apply the generalized sylvester criterion for PSD matrices https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4145638/a-is-positive-semidefinite-iff-textdet-b-k-geq-0/ (and re-use said $2\times 2$ case)

Comment: I suppose you could do it that way.  Spectral theorem isn't needed per se, just basic congruence. Anyway if $A=B^TB$ then $a_{i,i}=0= \big \Vert \mathbf b_i\big \Vert_2^2\implies \mathbf b_i = \mathbf 0$  thus $\mathbf b_i^T\mathbf b_k =0$ for all of row/col i.