# Semidefiniteness using Leading Principal Minors

Tags: optimization, positive-semidefinite, hessian-matrix

From Simon and Blume (p. 391):

Using a bordered hessian *H* with *m* constraints, to verify positive definiteness, check that *det(H<sub>2m+1</sub>)* has the same sign as *(-1)<sup>m</sup>* and that all larger leading principal minors have this sign too.

To verify negative definiteness, check that *det(H<sub>2m+1</sub>)* has the same sign as *(-1)<sup>m+1</sup>* and that the leading principal minors of larger order alternate in sign.

I wanted to know if there are similar rules in checking for positive/negative **semi**-definiteness, since the objective function need only be quasiconcave/quasiconvex for my purposes. Is there a resource with as clean notation as this?

Comment: in general you check that leading principal minors are all positive to conclude positive definiteness of a real symmetric matrix.  For mere positive semi-definiteness you need to check all principal minors.  I gave a proof here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4145638/a-is-positive-semidefinite-iff-textdet-b-k-geq-0/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are. You have to look at all the principal minors, not just the leading principal minors. See the old book by W.L. Ferrar, Algebra published by Oxford U.P.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you!