Why this proof can't be used to "generalize" sylvester's criterion for positive semidefinite matrices?
The sylvester's criterion for positive definite matrices states "A self-adjoint matrix A is positive definite if and only if all the leading principal minors of A have strictly positive determinants".
If we were to focus on the "if" direction (which is more challenging to prove), a possible approach, as suggested in the book "$\textit{Advanced Linear and Matrix Algebra}$" by Nathaniel Johnston, could follow by induction using the fact of such statement being evident on 1x1 matrices (base case) :
For the inductive step, assume that the theorem holds for $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ matrices. To see that it must then hold for $n\times n$ matrices, notice that if $A\in$ $\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{F})$ is as in the statement of the theorem and $\det(A_k)>0$ for all $1\leq k\leq n$, then $\det(A)>0$ and (by the inductive hypothesis) $A_{n-1}$ is positive definite. Let $\lambda_i$ and $\lambda_j$ be any two eigenvalues of $A$ with corresponding orthogonal eigenvectors $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{w}$, respectively. Then define $\mathbf{x}=w_n\mathbf{v}-\nu_n\mathbf{w}$ and notice that $\mathbf{x}\neq\mathbf{0}$ (since $\{\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w}\}$ is linearly independent), but $x_n=w_n\nu_n-\nu_nw_n=0.$ Since $x_n=0$ and $A_{n-1}$ is positive definite, it follows that
$$\begin{aligned}\text{0}&<\mathbf{x}^*A\mathbf{x}\\&=(w_n\mathbf{v}-\nu_n\mathbf{w})^*A(w_n\mathbf{v}-\nu_n\mathbf{w})\\&=|w_n|^2\mathbf{v}^*A\mathbf{v}-w_n\overline{\nu_n}\mathbf{w}^*A\mathbf{v}-\nu_n\overline{w_n}\mathbf{v}^*A\mathbf{w}+|\nu_n|\mathbf{w}^*A\mathbf{w}\\&=\lambda_i|w_n|^2\mathbf{v}^*\mathbf{v}-\lambda_iw_n\overline{\nu_n}\mathbf{w}^*\mathbf{v}-\lambda_j\nu_n\overline{w_n}\mathbf{v}^*\mathbf{w}+\lambda_j|\nu_n|^2\mathbf{w}^*\mathbf{w}\\&=\lambda_i|w_n|^2\|\mathbf{v}\|^2-0-0+\lambda_j|\nu_n|^2\|\mathbf{w}\|^2.\end{aligned}$$
Therefore, we can notice that it is not possible that both $\lambda_i\leq0$ and $\lambda_j\leq0.$ Since $\lambda_i$ and $\lambda_j$ were arbitrary eigenvalues of $A$, it follows that $A$ must have at most one non-positive eigenvalue. However, if it had exactly one non-positive eigenvalue then it would be the case that det$(A)=\lambda_1\lambda_2\cdots\lambda_n\leq0$,which we know is not the case. It follows that all of $A’$s eigenvalues are strictly positive, so $A$ is positive definite.
Note: if $\nu_n = w_n =0$ we instead
define $\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{v}$ to fix
up the proof.
I simply cannot spot where such induction proof would fail if we used it to prove, with small modifications over the inequalities, the statement "If all the leading principal minors of A have non-negative determinants, then A is positive semidefinite". If it indeed is not enough to generalize, then is there a way of "extending" such proof?

To confirm that there is indeed an issue, the article here provides a 3-by-3 counterexample (Eq. (3)): all the leading principal minors have nonnegative determinants, but the matrix has a negative eigenvalue and thus cannot be PSD. (Alternatively, note that $v^\top Z_1 v=-1$ where $v=(1,0,-1)^\top$.)

The author’s proof is not correct. E.g. let ${\mathbf e_1,\mathbf e_2,\mathbf e_3}$ be the standard basis of $\mathbb R^3$ and let $A=I_3$. Take $\mathbf v=\mathbf e_1$ and $\mathbf w=\mathbf e_2$. Then $w_3=v_3=0$. Hence $\mathbf x=w_3\mathbf v-v_3\mathbf w=0$, despite the fact that $\mathbf v$ and $\mathbf w$ are linearly independent. You may see my answer for a correct argument.

@user1551 I added a note that includes how the author handled such edge case.

@Semiclassical Indeed, there are practical examples of how the "generalized" statement is false, however the question is where the adapted proof would be failing.

Regardless of whether the author’s proof is valid or not, when the leading principal minors are merely nonnegative, it can happen that $v_n=0\ne w_n$ and $\lambda_i=0>\lambda_j$. Thus $\mathbf x^\ast A\mathbf x=0$ although $A$ is not PSD.

As far as extending the criterion to check for positive semi-definiteness goes, you check that all principal minors are $\geq 0$.  See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4145638/a-is-positive-semidefinite-iff-textdet-b-k-geq-0

@user1551 Can't we choose eigenvectors $v,w$ such that $v_nw_n \neq 0$. I guess the argument is: even that's possible, we can have $v_i$ strictly positve while $v_j$ strictly negative such that $\lambda_i|w_n|^2|\mathbf{v}|^2+\lambda_j|\nu_n|^2|\mathbf{w}|^2 = 0$.

@user1551 If instead the statement were to suppose that indeed "All principal minors (not only the leading ones) are non-negative" , does that mean that this proof (with adjusted inequalities) would work once proven that it is not possible to have $v_n=w_n=0$ with $\lambda_i = 0 > \lambda_j$ ? That is, so far, this proof was only good enough to show that there may exist at most one negative eigenvalue along with some extra restrictions ?

@excitedGoose How will you leverage the condition "All principal minors are non-negative" in the proof?

The proof would fail in the PSD case. At the end, we would have $\det(A)\ge 0$ and that there would exist at most one strictly negative eigenvalue of $A$. However, $\lambda_1\cdots\lambda_n\le0$ would not contradict $\det(A)\ge 0$.
